# Varnish for Acrylic Painting

Tags: preservation, acrylic-paint, storage, varnish

I was using the yellow wood varnishes, which are easily available in hardware stores, to seal my acrylic painting. They are cheap but the problem with them is that they leave yellowish shine which changes the original color of my painting and which increases with the time.

I am in search of an alternative which is, more or less, equally cheap. I don't want to spend much on the varnish.

Comment: I’m closing this question because it is a duplicate of another (currently deleted) question.

Comment: @Joachim -Thanks. That's what I was looking for... Above says closed for off-topic so it is not listing the duplicate link.

Comment: @rebusB Yes, strange, in the editing history it even says the "Post [was] Closed as "Not suitable for this site"" by me. I merged the two. I'm guessing it might take a while for all comments to have been merged. (Nevermind; apparently that's only for merging answers -> reopened and closed as duplicate.)